# class-transformer @Type with multiple subTypes that have the same class for different types

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

Stay with me its gonna get confusing:

- I am using NestJs with class-validator/transformer
- There is an array that can consist of 2 types
- I use the @Type to define the ite via discriminator
- I use Transform because it is needed in Serialization or else it would create empty objects

Now the issue is, my discriminator is an enum size 7, 6 point towards one class, and the last one to the other. The issue is, for some reason no matter the enum type, it gets always changed to the first subType when Serialized.

```js
enum DiscrType = {A: "a", B: "b", C: "c"}

class Discriminator {
 @IsEnum(DiscrType)
 type: DiscrType 
}

class ClassONE extends Discriminator {...}
class ClassTWO extends Discriminator {...}

class Stuff {
 @Type(() => Discriminator, {
    discriminator: {
      property: 'type',
      subTypes: [
        { value: ClassTWO, name: DiscrType.C},
        { value: ClassONE, name: DiscrType.A}, // Always turns into this value even if it was B
        { value: ClassONE, name: DiscrType.B},
   
      ],
    },
    keepDiscriminatorProperty: true,
  })
 @Transform(
    ({ value }) =>
      value?.map((object: ClassONE | ClassTWO ) =>
        object.type === DiscrType.C
          ? plainToClass(classTWO, object)
          : plainToClass(ClassONE, object),
      ),
  )
  @ValidateNested({each: true})
  property: (ClassONE | ClassTWO )[]
}
```

Behaviour:

```js
new Stuff({type: DiscrType.B,...}) // Serialization with Class Serializer

// Expected: 
x = {type: "b",...}
// Actual: 
x = {type: "a",...}
```

Comment: @AluanHaddad if u read my question, you would understand, that the issue is not solved by the documentation, the docs have 3 types, with 3 classes, I have 3 types with 2 classes! and that causes the issue